# Why don't multiple threads have to share a lock to call mmap like they do malloc/calloc/sbrk?

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, thread-synchronization

I'm working with [ptmalloc](https://github.com/hustfisher/ptmalloc/blob/master/malloc.c), and something interesting I came across is when an arena runs out of available chunks (and the top chunk is not large enough) and has to either extend the arena using `sbrk()` or allocate a non-contiguous region using `mmap()`. What particularly stood out to me is that in order to allocate more memory using `sbrk()`, a lock had to be acquired before being able to call it (in addition to the lock previously obtained to be in sole possession of the current arena). However, no lock needs to be acquired before calling `mmap()`. I have included the specific parts of the `sys_alloc()` function from the malloc.c file included in the ptmalloc implementation (for reference) below:

- Call to extend arena using `sbrk()`:

```
if (HAVE_MORECORE && tbase == CMFAIL) { /* Try noncontiguous MORECORE */
    size_t asize = granularity_align(nb + TOP_FOOT_SIZE + SIZE_T_ONE);
    if (asize < HALF_MAX_SIZE_T) {
      char* br = CMFAIL;
      char* end = CMFAIL;
      ACQUIRE_MORECORE_LOCK(); /* LOCK */
      br = (char*)(CALL_MORECORE(asize));
      end = (char*)(CALL_MORECORE(0));
      RELEASE_MORECORE_LOCK(); /* UNLOCK */
      if (br != CMFAIL && end != CMFAIL && br < end) {
        size_t ssize = end - br;
        if (ssize > nb + TOP_FOOT_SIZE) {
          tbase = br;
          tsize = ssize;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

- Call to extend arena using `mmap()`:

```
if (HAVE_MMAP && tbase == CMFAIL) {  /* Try MMAP */
    size_t req = nb + TOP_FOOT_SIZE + SIZE_T_ONE;
    size_t rsize = granularity_align(req);
    if (rsize > nb) { /* Fail if wraps around zero */
      char* mp = (char*)(CALL_MMAP(rsize));
      if (mp != CMFAIL) {
        tbase = mp;
        tsize = rsize;
        mmap_flag = IS_MMAPPED_BIT;
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help understanding why this is able to work even with multiple threads that have the exact same memory pattern (and thus have to extend their arenas at the same time) without having to use locks (i.e., how `mmap()` is guaranteed to return distinct addresses, even if called simultaneously with a NULL suggested address) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- In the code snippet using `sbrk()`. It is used to increased the process global heap area. Two calls are issued: the 1st one extends the heap area by *rsize* bytes and the second gets the resulting address of the new top of the heap (the so-called program's break). The heap area is shared by all the threads of the process. The cuurent top is a global variable for all the threads. Hence, it is protected by a mutex whenever a thread modifies it (shrink/grow operations);
- In the code snippet using `mmap()`, the current thread is allocating a single memory mapped area for itself. The resulting address is only for the calling thread. Hence, no mutual exclusion is necessary from the ptmalloc global data structures point of view as the latter are not modified. A flag **IS_MMAPPED_BIT** is set in the internal allocated header to indicate to ptmalloc that this is a memory mapped region when it is requested to free it. Concerning `mmap()` internals, the mutual exclusion is managed inside the kernel.